# if i call a non synchronized method from my synchronized method is non synchronized method thread safe?

Tags: java, methods, thread-safety

I i make a call to noonsynchronized method from within my synchronized method is it thread safe?

I have 2 methods as follows:

```
public class MyClass{

 void synchronized doSomething1(){

   doSomething2();
  }

void doSomething2(){
 //will this block of code be synchronized if called only from doSomething1??
 }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

If `doSomething2()` is only called from `doSomething1()`, then it will only be called by a single thread *for a single instance of `MyClass`*. It could still be called from different threads at the same time, via different instances - so if it acts on any shared data which may not be specific to the instance of `MyClass`, it's still not guaranteed to fix all threading issues.

Basically, you need to think carefully about any mutable shared state used by multiple threads - there are no easy fixes to that, if you *need* mutable shared state. In your particular case you'd also need to make *sure* that `doSomething2()` was only called from `doSomething1()` - which would mean making it private to start with...

Answer (score 3):

When calling `doSomething1()` the *caller's* `Thread` *locks* on the *monitor* of the *instance* of `MyClass`. Until that thread's execution exits `doSomething1` the lock will remain which includes if it goes into `doSomething2`. This will cause other threads to block when attempting to lock.

Keep in mind:
`synchronized` does not thread-safe it make.

Further info:

- [JLS 3rd Ed 17.1 Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.1)

Answer (score 1):

If `doSomething2()` is called ONLY from `doSomething1()` then yes - it is thread safe.

Comment: If doSomething2() is called ONLY from doSomething1() from a single thread then yes.

Comment: @Froyo: Why -1? When it will be not thread safe in your opinion? If The body of doSomething1() is the only place in the code which calls `doSomething2()` then there can be only one thread running doSomething1() on single VM, and so only one thread running doSomething2().

Comment: @Froyo: if there is a single thread only, then there is no need for using `synchronized` at all.